# Copying a unique_ptr char array to another unique_ptr char array after resizing is missing letter by the end of char

Tags: c++, arrays, resize, unique-ptr

## Problem Description

In the following source code i am doing the following things:

- create a string name with "Hello"
- create an unique_ptr ptr char array having a  size of name.size() + 1 size
- memcpy the string to the ptr array
- add null-terminated character
- create an unique_ptr newptr char array having a size of strlen(ptr.get()) +2
- memcpy ptr to newptr
- release ptr
- add X to hello
- add null-terminated character

## Source Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory> 
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  std::string name = "hello";
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[name.size()+1]);
  memcpy(ptr.get(),name.c_str(),name.size());    
  ptr[name.size()] ='\0';
  
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> newptr(new char[strlen(ptr.get())+2]);
  memcpy(newptr.get(), ptr.get(),strlen(ptr.get()));
  newptr[strlen(newptr.get())-1]= 'X';
  newptr[strlen(newptr.get())]= '\0';
  ptr.release(); //RELEASE POINTER
  
  char* c = newptr.get();
  std::cout<< c << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

## Output

The expected output should be: helloX

But i am only getting Hellx

I don't know why it isn't working. I don't understand why The character X isn't being added to the end of newPtr char array.

Sorry IF i butchered the uniquer pointers. IT's my first try

Comment: `strlen` doesn't include the null terminator so `strlen(ptr.get())+2` only makes an array that's 1 bigger than the one pointer to by `ptr`.

Comment: Just to be clear, in an actual project you should use `std::string` for all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> memcpy(newptr.get(), ptr.get(),strlen(ptr.get()));
> ```

This copies everything up to, but excluding the null terminator.

> ```
> newptr[strlen(newptr.get())-1]= 'X';
> ```

This calls `strlen` with a non-null-terminated (and partially uninitialised) string. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
> ptr.release(); //RELEASE POINTER
> ```

This causes memory to leak!

Comment: oh yes it's reset.

Comment: i don't know I tried sizeof instead of strlen i am trying to see. Still don't get it.

Comment: @gringo `sizeof` of a pointer is unrelated to the size of the pointed array.

Comment: @gringo You are trying to manipulate C strings, so use `strcpy` and `strlen`, not `memcpy` or `sizeof`. To concatenate strings use `strcat`. Use the functions that are designed for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @john ok. changed memcpy to strcpy. I still don't get what am I doing wrong. I tried with raw char * still didn't work I don't know what point i am missing

Comment: The problem is this `newptr[strlen(newptr.get())-1]= 'X';`. You have one less character than you think you should have, doesn't the `-1` look a bit suspicious? But the easy way is to use `strcat` it's a function designed to concatenate strings.  `strcat(newptr.get(), "X");` Simple

Comment: yesss u are right!!! . This was wrong you are right!! man I got lost again.

Thanks a lot @john